# If $D$, $E$, $F$ are feet of altitudes in $\triangle ABC$, so that the perpendicular bisector of $EF$ bisects $BC$

Tags: geometry

> Let $D$, $E$, $F$ be the feet of the altitudes from $A$, $B$, $C$ in a $\triangle ABC$. Prove that the perpendicular bisector of $EF$ also bisects $BC$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let PQ be the perpendicular bisector of EF cutting BC at R.

$\angle BFC = \angle CEB = 90$ degrees means there is a circle passing through BFEC with BC as diameter.

Suppose that the center of that circle is S (a point on BC such that BS = SC) which is NOT on PQ.

But EF is a chord of that circle too , and therefore the center of that circle must lie on PRQ.

Thus, S must coincide with R.

The result then follows.